# proper way to redirect user to their origin page?

Tags: angular, typescript, url, redirect, referrer

I have an application (`B`) that is linked in another (`A`). Basically the user is in `A` and they can click into `B`.

I'm saving this URL/URI link in a service. This is what I'm doing in the redirect service:

```
export class DirectService {
  private redirect_uri: any;
  constructor() {}

  setRedirectUri(userUri): void {
    this.redirect_uri = userUri;
  }
  getRedirectUri() {
    return this.redirect_uri;
  }
```

I'm setting `redirect_uri` in my container when its initialized.
`this.redirectService.setRedirectUri(document.referrer);`
according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) this should save the page `A` that links `B`

I have button that when clicked will do perform this function:

```
onClose(): void {
    window.location.href(this.redirectService.getRedirectUri());
  }
```

I'm getting an error on the `href` saying this:
*This expression is not callable.
Type 'String' has no call signatures*

I've also tried using `router` like this:

`this.router.navigate(this.redirectService.getRedirectUri())`
but that gives me this error:

```
*main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: J.reduce is not a function*
    *at ee (main.js:1:2481641)*
    *at At (main.js:1:2480222)*
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error you are seeing is pointing out the fact that `window.location.href` isn't a function, it's a string. Simply assign to it like so:

```
window.location.href = this.redirectService.getRedirectUri();
// or just
window.location = this.redirectService.getRedirectUri();
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `window.location.href`, you simply assign to it:

```js
window.location.href = this.redirectService.getRedirectUri();
```